# Single AngularJS codebase to support web and mobile

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this idea for a new project which should run from iOS, Android and as a website. I wanted to have the exact same interface on the web and mobile.

I found Ionic (with Cordova) to support both iOS and Android. My question is: can I still use the same code base (or most of it) to serve the website?

Comment: Please be referred following link http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/deploy-ionic-app-as-a-website/2845

Comment: Browser Support
Ionic is focused on building native/hybrid mobile apps rather than mobile websites.

As such, our browser support tends to be whatever Web View API is available to native apps on a given platform. For Ionic 1.0.0 "uranium-unicorn", that means UIWebView for iOS 7+, and Android 4.1 and up. Windows Phone and FirefoxOS support is on our roadmap.

Comment: So basically if I opt for Ionic, i can forget about single code base?

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can and that why its so amazing, the challenge will be to make a nice responsive design